# Fronting of a to æ in European Portuguese

Tags: vowels, portuguese, vowel-harmony, vowel-height

In Portuguese there are two accepted reasons vowels in verbs alternate in height.

The vowel harmonizing rule states that where the theme vowel (*a* from -*ar*, *e* from -*er*, and *i* from -*ir*) is deleted from the conjugation and retains tonic stress, the root vowel is changed to match the height of the theme vowel..

- For example, the verb `levar` has a root vowel `e` whose height is **mid**, and a theme vowel `a` whose height is **low**. Therefore, where the theme vowel is omitted from a conjugation, such as in the first person indicative (*I lead*) the `e` from `levo`  widens from mid to low `lɛvo`.
- The same is true with `servir`, the `e` (**mid**) narrows to `i` (**narrow**), so the first person indicative (*I serve*) is not `*servo`, but it is instead `sirvo`.

The second vowel alternation rule is a general lowering of theme vowels for **mid** height root vowels, where the first rule does not apply.

- `servir` whose root vowel, `e`, is **mid** is lowered to `ɛ` which is **open** in many conjugations, especially where the thematic vowel is not changed, and retains the tonic stress. Thus - `sɛrves`, `sɛrve`, `sɛrvem`. And in `muver` the `o` theme vowel is lowered to `ɔ`: `mɔves`, `mɔve`, `mɔvem`.

**Given that these two are the only accepted vowel alternation conventions in Portuguese, what is causing some speakers to alternate the `a` in `cantar` to a fronted `æ` or even `e`?**  This convention is especially prevalent in the first person form `kænto`.

I'll put a URL to a song here if anybody is interested in hearing it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WGTENlPlt8#t=31.

Comment: As a native Portuguese speaker, I had never paid attention to this vowel harmonizing rule. Thanks for the question!

Comment: When I first saw your question, I figured you'd be talking about *-a* to *-as* where I hear some raising in European Portuguese.  Do you notice the same raising with *falar*/*falo*?  Or *jantar*/*janto*?

Comment: @guifa This is a really good question, I do notice the same rising in janto, I think people in Lisboa say something like /'jen tu/.

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves if it happens with *janto* then but not *falo*, then it is likely being raised by the nasalizing *n*. What about keeping the nasal bowl vowel but a different consonant? *cambio* de *cambiar* or *canso* de *cansar*?  What about a word with just a nasal consonant that doesn't  nasalize the vowel? Like *amo*? Just to try to narrow things down

Comment: Note: 'Mover' is pronounced 'muver' and its singular first person 'movo' is pronounced 'movo'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, I would have thought the *canto* vowel change (at least how it's pronounced in the song you~ve linked) is because it comes before an 'n'. The 'an' sound in (at least São Paulista) Portuguese to me always seems to do this.

Comment: So, do you agree that the singer says something equivalent to /'ken tu/ or /'kæn tu/? Do you know of any other environments where /n/ can change the vowels?

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves Yeas he does. It's very common. I'd suspect slight nasalisation (which is everywhere in Portuguese) of the *n* is what cause the shift. Another example is *banho*, where the stronger nasalisation is evident in the spelling. This happens with other vowels too, such as in *suponho*. To answer your other question, since the shift happens with nasalisation, one other example environment where you can find this is where the *a* is specifically nasalised with the accent marker, e.g., *irmã*.